# How do you get the Alias of a bluetooth low energy device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

As shown in this picture here :

[BLE Scanner getting Alias if exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRFd9.png)

I am trying to do the same on my app. I'm able to get the device name and pretty much all the information that i need, but i'm unable to get the Alias, knowing by the android App BLE scanner that first : it exists, and second : it's possible to get it.

I did try to use that method :

```
try {

            Method m = device.getNative().getClass().getMethod("getAlias");
            Object res = null;
            if (m != null ) {
                res = m.invoke(device.getNative());
            }
            if(res != null)
                Alias = res.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(name == null)
            name = device.getName_debug();
```

Where device.getNative() access the lower level instance of the BluetoothDevice.
But it's returning the device name not the alias.

**Note : Maybe the "Alias" is not the right word to describe the variable that i'm trying to access.**

If someone could help i would appreciate.

Comment: what is the device alias? Why you think it is different from the name?

Comment: The thing is i know that there is a difference between the device name and the alias. The alias is added so that we would be able to really differentiate devices or group them with a specific name. BLE Scanner is able to do so, so there is a difference and we are able to access that information when it exists. And ofc i don't mean the mac address.